# Scope "method" is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I am trying to incorporate scopes into my application. Here is a line:

```
scope :important, -> { where(important: true) }
```

I am getting the following error when loading a page:

```
undefined method `scope' for TodosController:Class
```

Is there a gem to fix this?

Comment: Are you defining your scope in the model? How are you calling it in your controller? Please post both if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're wrongly trying to define your scope in your `todos_controller.rb` controller when it belongs in your `todo.rb` model.

Move that definition there and then you can use it in your controller with `Todo.important`.

Please read the [Rails guide on this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) before you go any further.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that